# How can I use 1 function to do several things depending on a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

The question title is a little confusing, but basically, what I need is to have a function set an element's inner HTML based on another element's id

Here's the HTML:

```
<button id="a" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Option 1</button>
<button id="b" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Option 2</button>
<button id="c" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Option d</button>

<p id="testarea"></p>
```

So depending on which button they pressed, the function should do something slightly different each time

```
function test(){
  if(document.getElementById('a').id == "a")
     document.getElementById('testarea').innerHTML = "Hi";
}
```

For whatever reason, that doesn't work. Even if it did, it would be very inefficient in my opinion, to repeatedly copy and paste and slightly edit that if statement.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use bootstrap, i have another solution but this one is using jquery:

**HTML**

I added options class so atleast the selector will be limited to those buttons and removed the `onlick()`:

```
<button id="a" class="btn btn-primary options">Option 1</button>
<button id="b" class="btn btn-primary options">Option 2</button>
<button id="c" class="btn btn-primary options">Option d</button>

<p id="testarea"></p>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.options').on('click', function () {
    var link_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var test_text = '';

    switch (link_id) {
        case 'a': test_text = 'Hi'; break;
        default: break;
    }

    $('#testarea').html(test_text);
});
```

On button click, you get the `id` then use that in a `switch statement` where you put the conditions. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vux9f3sb/).

Answer (score 1):

Twitter-Bootstrap comes with jQuery so you can use that to make things *much* easier / simpler. Add this code:

```
function test() {
    var id = $(this).id.trim().toLowerCase(); // Makes lowercase, keep in mind
    
    switch (id) {
        case 'a':
            // More Code here, here's some sample code:
            $(this).html('Test A');
            break;
        case 'b':
            $(this).html('Test B');
            break;
    };
}
```

This uses `switch`.

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case.
>
> **The switch statement is fast, and easier to understand then tons of `if`s**

#### Read more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<button id="a" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test(this)">Option 1</button>
```

js;

```
function test(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;
    if (id == "a")
        document.getElementById('testarea').innerHTML = "Hi";
}
```

Comment: @vihan1086 not pass this obj, the id will be "undefined", [demo](http://jsbin.com/sawiziboni/1/)